# Slicing Lists with Variable Based Index

Tags: python, variables, indexing, splice

How can I slice a list with an index that is based off of a variable?

i.e.

```
splitMe = range(0,10)

startPlace = 3
endPlace = 5

splitMe[startPlace:endPlace] #<------This is essentially what I need
```

This way I can input different numbers into startPlace and endPlace and get a different slice. This probably seems trivial, but I am cutting sections out of 230,000 lines of data. There are calculations behind startPlace and endPlace that have to do with dates and times.

This is what I have now:

```
#Find matching data with datetime
for a, line in enumerate (Time):
    if line == startDate:
        print "Slice starts at:", a

for c, line in enumerate (Time):
    if line == endDate:
        print "Slice ends at:", c

#Create lists
slice_laser_c = [x for x in laser_C if a <= x < c]
```

**EDIT**
When I run this code, it prints "Slice starts at: 0" and "Slice ends at: 5" which is exactly what it"s supposed to do. 
**END EDIT**
When I print slice_laser_c I get

```
[] #<----- Essentially, this is the problem
```

In a simple sense, this is what's going on:

```
big_list = range(0,10)
a = 2
c = 5

BetweenList = [x for x in big_list if a <= x < c]
print BetweenList
```

Comment: Hint: what do you see if you do `print a, c` right before the `slice_laser_c` line?

Comment: In any case, If the criteria for finding the start and end indexes is just an equality check, it may be more efficient to just do `a = Time.find(startDate)`, rather than iterating through the list manually.

Comment: I see that's a problem. 
`a = 223632
c = 223632`

Comment: Pardon me. I meant `Time.index`, not `Time.find`.

Comment: That shrunk my code! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the splice syntax built into Python? (Maybe I'm not seeing something)

Like:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a=3
c=7
split_list = list[a:(c+1)] #<-----The +1 is because the splice syntax goes to end-1
print split_list
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that, that's exactly what I needed. I tried `list[start:end]` but it failed for some reason. Well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appers to be that you are iterating right through all the `Times` without stopping when you find the values you want. Therefore at the end of both loops `a` and `c` are at their maximum value. Maybe you want to `break` the loop once you have found the value you want?

Comment: That appears to have fixed what Kevin mentioned above, `a` and `c` now report as the values they should be (`0` and `5`). Now I need to fix my line comprehension.